# How to execute countifs (less than or greater than) in power query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, countif, sumifs

I have few columns with values ranging from 0 - 5. I want a count of all values less than 5('<5').  Please help. This will help me to create pareto.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KORFQ.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Put some sample data with your expected output.